# Call field from inherited model Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, odoo-9

Let me explain what I'm trying to do.

On `stock` module, when You navigate to whatever operation (picking) type, being it a tree or form view, some of the fields that are shown are from `product.product`, like, for example `name`.

Now, the model `product.product` has a field called `price`, so, I need to show product price on `stock.picking` movements.

Since the `stock.picking` model doesn't inherit the `price` field, I'm creating a little module, to inherit `price` from `product.product`, and then show it on `stock.picking`.

It is a third module beside `stock` and `product`.

Now, in my `models.py` I declare:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api

class StockMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move'

    @api.onchange('name','product_id','move_line_tax_ids','product_uom_qty')

    price_unit = fields.Float( digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price'), string='Price')
```

In my `view.xml` I add this field to `stock.picking`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<openerp>
<data>

<record id="view_stock_move_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Stock Move Price Tree</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="state" position="before">
            <field name="price_unit"/>
        </field>
    </field> 
</record>

<record id="view_stock_move_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Stock Move Price Form</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="state" position="before">
                <field name="price_unit"/>
            </field>
    </field>
</record>

</data>
</openerp>
```

Every time I try to run this, it throws me on console:

```
2016-10-15 05:23:44,821 21578 ERROR argentina werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoo_danisan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoo_danisan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/service/server.py", line 246, in app
return self.app(e, s)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/http.py", line 1495, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/http.py", line 1644, in dispatch
ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/http.py", line 365, in registry
return openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get(self.db) if self.db else None
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 355, in get
update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 386, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 334, in load_modules
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 123, in load_module_graph
load_openerp_module(package.name)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/module.py", line 331, in load_openerp_module
__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/module.py", line 61, in load_module
mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/motostion_addons/stock_move_price/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from . import models
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/motostion_addons/stock_move_price/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from . import models
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/motostion_addons/stock_move_price/models/models.py", line 10
price_unit = fields.Float( digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price'), string='Price')
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

I hope I've explained myself, if You need further explanation just ask me please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code:

Replace

```
price_unit = fields.Float( digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price'), string='Price')
```

with

```
price_unit = fields.Float(string='Price', digits=dp.get_precision('Product Price'))
```

And write below line in import section

```
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
```

Afterwards restart Odoo server and upgrade your custom module.

EDIT:

Replace

```
_inherit = 'stock.move'
```

with

```
_inherit = 'stock.picking'
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but now on view it says field 'price_unit' does not exist :/, that's weird, already restarted the odoo process, I was attempting to upgrade the module but this error came out

Comment: Right, it was my mistake, changed the _inherit statement to stock.picking lol, now the error says: ProgrammingError: foreign key constraint "stock_picking_price_unit_fkey" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "price_unit" and "id" are of incompatible types: numeric and integer.

Comment: Gonna ask a new question for that, Thank You.